# Debug error abort() has been called Qt

Tags: c++, qt

When adding this code I get the debug error. This function is called from a Dialog class if you need to see that code too I'll post it, but what I do there is convert QString to strings and int's and then call the function.

```
void MediaHandler::changeMedia(std::string title, std::string des, int publishYear,
                     int rating, std::string var1, int var2)
{
    int pos = this->find(title);

    Book *aBookPtr = dynamic_cast<Book*>(this->medias[pos]);
    Movie *aMoviePtr = dynamic_cast<Movie*>(this->medias[pos]);
    TvSeries *aTvSeriesPtr = dynamic_cast<TvSeries*>(this->medias[pos]);

    if(aBookPtr != nullptr)
    {
        aBookPtr->setTitle(title);
        aBookPtr->setDes(des);
        aBookPtr->setPublishYear(publishYear);
        aBookPtr->setRating(rating);
        aBookPtr->setAuthor(var1);
        aBookPtr->setNrOfPages(var2);
    }
    else if(aMoviePtr != nullptr)
    {
        aMoviePtr->setTitle(title);
        aMoviePtr->setDes(des);
        aMoviePtr->setPublishYear(publishYear);
        aMoviePtr->setRating(rating);
        aMoviePtr->setMainActor(var1);
        aMoviePtr->setMovieLength(var2);
    }
    else if(aMoviePtr != nullptr)
    {
        aTvSeriesPtr->setTitle(title);
        aTvSeriesPtr->setDes(des);
        aTvSeriesPtr->setPublishYear(publishYear);
        aTvSeriesPtr->setRating(rating);
        aTvSeriesPtr->setMainActor(var1);
        aTvSeriesPtr->setNrOfEpisodes(var2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should verify that `title` is found and `pos` is valid, at least.

Comment: What does your debugger say?  What happens if you reduce this to just `setTitle` and the call that uses `var2`?  (Which will make the code easier to reason about).

Comment: Found the error thanks hyde. The stuff you said were not the errors but it made me realise what the error was :D